# Digest::MD5 in Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, rubygems, md5, irb, ruby-1.9.3

I'm running into something weird here.
I have an "authenticator" that relies on ND5 to hash a certain string we match as password. The problem when I run my tests is this:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `md5' for #<CASServer::Authenticators::Billing:0x007fd8e6c906a0>
./models/authenticators/billing.rb:63:in `validate'
./routes/login.rb:166:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Server>'
./routes/login.rb:158:in `each'
./routes/login.rb:158:in `block in <class:Server>'
(eval):2:in `click_button'
./features/step_definitions/when_steps.rb:32:in `/^I enter "(.*)" as username and the generated username password and log in$/'
./features/rubycas.login.feature:14:in `When I enter "username" as username and the generated username password and log in'
```

So basically he does not recognize the MD5 as part of the Digest library.
This problem occurs when running the tests in the IDE, as well as in the IRB console:

```
1.9.3-p125 :001 > require "digest/md5" and Digest::MD5("test")
NoMethodError: undefined method `MD5' for Digest:Module
```

However, when I run the following:

```
[root@DCUDEV01 /home/morn/rubycas/current]# ruby
require "digest/md5" and Digest::MD5("test")
```

I receive no errors, dumps or exceptions. Ruby just accepts it.
What am I missing in order to get this MD5 stuff working?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Digest::MD5 is not a method but a module.  Try

```
Digest::MD5.digest("test")
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the documentation of the method, please?

Comment: [Documentation here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/). Somehow I can't find the _official_ documentation for
    Digest::MD5

Answer (score 0):

I found it confusing, it doesn't seem like `.digest` is correct. I can't say it is wrong either...

Commenter @reconbot got it right, IMO, but I saw the comment only after coming back to improve this QA, I think a comment isn't visible enough.

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/MD5.html

Below is an example usage for md5 hasing for gibbon usage, the mailchimp gem.

```
md5_hashed_email_address = Digest::MD5.hexdigest("john.doe@example.com")
```